# How to get code coverage for test class?

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I want to cover the catch part of code but I am unable to get this

main class:

```
public static void updateAccount(List<account> accList){
   try{
      for(account acc : accList){
         acc.Name = 'Some Name';
      }
   }
   catch(exception e){
      system.debug(e.getMessage());
   }
 }
```

test class:

```
@isTest
public static void testUpdateAccount(){
List<account> accList = [Select Id from Account]; //Accounts were created in @testSetup method
className.updateAccount(accList);
}
```

Here I was expecting the error `SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Name` but code is not given any error. Catch block of main class in not get cover in code coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove that try/catch, as it is impossible for that code to throw a (catchable) exception. In general, seeing `catch(Exception e)` is a red flag. If you're going to catch an exception, you should know what type(s) of exceptions you're expecting.

The reason why you're not getting the "without querying the requested field" exception is because you're not trying to access the field value, you're *setting* the field value.

Setting fields that weren't queried is fine.
Trying to access fields that weren't queried (or otherwise set in code) is not fine.